# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 13 during flutter null-safety migration

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, dart-null-safety

I'm following [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migration-tool) guide to migrate [my flutter project](https://github.com/christianreiser/insightme) to null safety.

At step 2 when issuing the command

```
$ dart migrate
```

Also I'm wondering if it's normal that there are no issues found during project analysis:

```
Migrating /home/chrei/code/insight_me

See https://dart.dev/go/null-safety-migration for a migration guide.

Analyzing project...
[---/]No analysis issues found.
```

Below I get an error during Compiling instrumentation information:

```
Generating migration suggestions...
[---]


Compiling instrumentation information...
[----------------------------------------------------------\]
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 13
    #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/array.dart:268:52)
    #1      BestPracticesVerifier._targetKindsFor (package:analyzer/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1582:38)
    #2      BestPracticesVerifier.visitAnnotation (package:analyzer/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:250:17)
    #3      AnnotationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:280:49)
    #4      NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
    #5      AnnotatedNodeImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:148:17)
    #6      ClassDeclarationImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1559:11)
    #7      RecursiveAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:707:10)
    #8      BestPracticesVerifier.visitClassDeclaration (package:analyzer/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:320:13)
    #9      ClassDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1536:49)
    #10     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7611:20)
    #11     CompilationUnitImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2141:21)
    #12     RecursiveAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:731:10)
    #13     CompilationUnitImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2134:49)
    #14     LibraryAnalyzer._computeHints (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:281:10)
    #15     LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:167:9)
    #16     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
    #17     LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:166:13)
    #18     LibraryAnalyzer.analyze (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:107:12)
    #19     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary2.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1416:65)
    #20     PerformanceLog.run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/performance_logger.dart:32:15)
    #21     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary2 (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1402:20)
    #22     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1395:15)
    #23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
    #24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
    #25     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1788:10)
    #26     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1710:10)
    #27     NullSafetyUnderstandingFlag.enableNullSafetyTypes (package:analyzer/dart/element/null_safety_understanding_flag.dart:42:12)
    #28     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1394:40)
    #29     AnalysisDriver.performWork (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:964:22)
    #30     AnalysisDriverScheduler._run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:2018:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

Dart version:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.12.4 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"
```

SDK constraints:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

Flutter Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.6.0-5.2.pre, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-36-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)  
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)  
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.  
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)  
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)  
[✓] Connected device (1 available)  
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If `dart migrate` itself is crashing, you should file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Dart SDK to the latest version solves it.

This issue was discussed and solved here https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46183